# Spark RDD saveAsTextFile gives java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.6.3 and trying to save rdd as textFile,but i am getting the following error.

```
pRdd = opRdd.coalesce(1);
opRdd.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/user1/Tarun/voucher");


java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/user1/Tarun/voucher/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201910261108_0002_m_000000_25 (exists=false, cwd=file:/opt/spark-1.6.3-3/work/app-20191026110834-0031/0)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:442)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:801)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1191)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1183)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is the issue ?

I have given 777 permission to Tarun folder.
I am submitting the code using spark-submit on Unix machine.

Comment: Did you give permission recursively i meant for voucher folder also?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution and would like to give solution.I change the folder to /tmp/Tarun/ and file was saved.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the explanation, from my side.
The directory, inside which files are stored, was created successfully but the files not. That's because driver (who creates the directory) and the executors (who create files) are executed using different users.
The executors are executed using the user used to run the spark Master.

Comment: how can we change the user for the executor?